# SwiftUI & Versioning: Incompatible?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

The SwiftUI preview does reproducibly not work if there is something (e.g., in the scheme pre/post triggers, or as build phase script) that modifies the project. In my case it is the versioning script that shall increase the build number of the project.

If so, the preview stops updating and says "Automatic preview updating paused".

Beside that it's pretty annoying to not being able to increase build numbers during SwiftUI development: does anyone here have a workaround or solution for that?